# How to filter BibLaTeX file with other fields than keyword?

Tags: biblatex

After 2 days of intensive research, reading the whole BibLaTeX doc and any forum discussions... I finally don't find the answer to my question.

I'm trying to sort out my huge `.bib` file. For this, I have some fields in my library that I created myself: `data={}`, `method={}`, etc. I'm trying to sort out my huge `.bib` file. I would like to sort my library by these fields. But I can only find examples or documentation

- by Keywords (but I created these fields, so as not to put them in the keywords)
- by category but (if I understand well) it is then necessary to list everything that we put in it, example of CTAN:

  ```
  \addtocategory{primary{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,averroes/bland}
  ```

  which implies that we list the author names of the category. My issue is that I DON'T WANT to rewrite the `.bib` file by filling `keywords` since I have hundreds of references, and because my sorting by other keys was a big thing to do!

Here is an example of 3 refs in my `.bib`, that I want to sort by `method` and by `data`:

```latex
Article{NGWA2017, 
author = {NGWA white papers}, 
title = {Integrated Surface Water-Groundwater Modeling}, 
journal = {NGWA white papers}, 
year = {2017}, 
data = {Water}, 
problematic = {Modeling}, }.

Article{ABBASZADEH2018192, 
Title = {Enhancing hydrologic data assimilation by evolutionary}, 
Author = {Peyman Abbaszadeh and Hamid Moradkhani and Hongxiang Yan}, Journal = {Advances in Water Resources}, 
Year = {2018}, 
Pages = {192 - 204}, 
Volume = {111}, 
Data = {Hydrology}, 
Keywords = {Particle Filters, Markov Chain Monte Carlo, Genetic algorithm, Hydrologic prediction}, 
method = {Particle filter}, 
problematic = {Assimilation}, }

Article{Adriaanse2017268, 
author = {Paulien I. Adriaanse and Robert}, 
title = {The effect of the runoff size on the pesticide concentration in runoff water}, 
journal = {Science of The Total Environment}, 
year = {2017}, 
volume = {584-585}, 
pages = {268 - 281}, 
data = {Pesticides, runoff}, 
keywords = {Pesticide}, 
problematic = {Modeling}
}.
```

I thought if I just did:

```latex
\nocite{*} 

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,title=Assimilation},problematic=assimilation]
\printbibliography [heading=subbibliography,type=article,title{Modeling},problematic=modeling]
```

it would work, like with `keywords`, or with `article`, or any other classic field? But then I get the error "keyval undefined".

Would you have some help suggesting me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant section of the `biblatex` manual for your problem is Section 3.7.9 on  Bibliography Filters and Checks. What you can do is to create specific `checks`:

```
\defbibcheck{assimilation}{
 \iffieldequalstr{problematic}{assimilation}{}{\skipentry}
}
```

and then

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,title=Assimilation,check=assimilation]
```

Assuming `problematic` has been defined as a field. `biblatex` offers the opportunity to define new fields for bib entries (and new entry types as well). To define a new bib field one can use the `\DeclareDatamodelField` command`, so, for the question as hand, something like.

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{problematic,data,method}
```

The definition should appear in a configuration file (or in a biblatex style file). See, section 4.5.4 of the `biblatex` manual (it can be invoked by `texdoc biblatex` from a terminal/command line).

In case one of the custom fields contains a comma-separated list of values (see the `data` field in the OP), the definition of the check is a bit more complicated:

```
\defbibcheck{runoff}{
    \def\mylist{}
    \def\mycom{\forcsvlist{\listadd\mylist}}
    \usefield{\mycom}{data}
    \ifinlist{runoff}{\mylist}{}{\skipentry}
}
```

A simple way to check that an item is a list is to use the `\ifinlist` command from `etoolbox`. However, the command works on an internal list. so the first three lines are to populate the internal `\mylist` with the values from the custom `data` field.

The MWE below contains two instances of `filecontents` environment. The first one is to create on the fly (on the working directory) the `biblatex-dm.cfg` file to store the definitions of the custom bib fields. The second instance is to populate a working bibliography to make the MWE self-contained.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{problematic,method,data}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{NGWA2017, 
author = {NGWA white papers}, 
title = {Integrated Surface Water-Groundwater Modeling}, 
journal = {NGWA white papers}, 
year = {2017}, 
data = {Water}, 
problematic = {Modeling}, }.

@Article{ABBASZADEH2018192, 
Title = {Enhancing hydrologic data assimilation by evolutionary}, 
Author = {Peyman Abbaszadeh and Hamid Moradkhani and Hongxiang Yan}, Journal = {Advances in Water Resources}, 
Year = {2018}, 
Pages = {192 - 204}, 
Volume = {111}, 
Data = {Hydrology}, 
Keywords = {Particle Filters, Markov Chain Monte Carlo, Genetic algorithm, Hydrologic prediction}, 
method = {Particle filter}, 
problematic = {Assimilation}, }

@Article{Adriaanse2017268, 
author = {Paulien I. Adriaanse and Robert}, 
title = {The effect of the runoff size on the pesticide concentration in runoff water}, 
journal = {Science of The Total Environment}, 
year = {2017}, 
volume = {584-585}, 
pages = {268 - 281}, 
data = {Pesticides, runoff}, 
keywords = {Pesticide}, 
problematic = {Modeling}
}. 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\defbibcheck{assimilation}{
 \iffieldequalstr{problematic}{Assimilation}{}{\skipentry}
}

\defbibcheck{runoff}{
    \def\mylist{}
    \def\mycom{\forcsvlist{\listadd\mylist}}
    \usefield{\mycom}{data}
    \ifinlist{runoff}{\mylist}{}{\skipentry}
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,title=Assimilation,check=assimilation]  

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,title=Runoff,check=runoff]  

\printbibliography
%
\end{document}
```

yielding

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I am almost there... Could you precise : "Assuming problematic has been defined as a field." How can I define a new field ? Do I need to define them at the beginningof each new latex document using this bibliography ? And how can I do that ?

Comment: PS : I guess you mean \iffieldequalstr ?

Comment: Since `\DeclareDatamodelFields` needs to be externalised to a `.dbx` file (or `biblatex-dm.cfg`, which I'm not too fond of) it may make this answer much more useful if it were to provide a full MWE that shows how things work.

Comment: Dear @Guido, you saved my week! It was much more difficult (for me) that I expected, and without your complete code I would not have been able to find it.

Comment: Some comments for future readers of this topic: (1) in case one of the custom fields contains a list of values (e.g. "data" here),  USE **commas** as separator, otherwise biblatex does not recognise there are several values. (2) About the **biblatex-dm.cfg** , locally you can fill it externally to the latex file, or you can include it the latex code as @Guido did in this example. On Overleaf (online), the error message says [File `biblatex-dm.cfg' already exists on the system.] , so you need to add one by hand in your folder, and the warning is still there but it uses your local .cfg file.

Comment: @moewe maybe could you explain why you don't like the .cfg solution? Thank you again!

Comment: @user3715453 Oh, I have no TeXnical reason for my dislike of `biblatex`-related `.cfg` files, it is mostly a matter of taste. If you add the code to the preamble or to a file you explicitly load you are less likely to forget about it and can sort of see that the code is there (and will notice if it is not there - either because it is literally not in the preamble or because you get an error because of missing files). If you put it into a local `.cfg` you may forget about the code and if you start a similar project but don't copy the local `.cfg` ...

Comment: ... there is no error, but you won't get the modifications it contains. If you decide to go for a global `.cfg` you need to remember that you are applying global modifications if you share your document with other people or install a new system. (But I guess similar things could be said about the other approaches ... and `.cfg`s can have their uses.)